# Product listing page is not working in Akeneo 2.3

Tags: product, akeneo

I have installed fresh akeneo 2.3 and now my product page is stuck on loading.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by giving apache user the ownership of 'pim-community-standard' directory.

Following are the commands I followed:

1. Find what USER apache is running as: login with root access:
   `` ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' ``
2. Find the web server user's group: `groups <apache_use>`
3. To give ownership to apache:
   `chown -R <apache_user>:<apache_group> pim-community-standard`

Hope this will help others.